# Web Services (SOAP) - How to work with xmlnodes contained in an interface

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

I've added in a service reference to my project which has generated several methods which are contained in an interface. Here is an example:

```
public interface ClientServiceSoap {
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="https://service.service.com/GetAgentsInGroup", ReplyAction="*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    System.Xml.XmlNode GetAgentsInGroup(string username, string password, int groupId);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="https://service.service.com/GetAgentsInGroup", ReplyAction="*")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Xml.XmlNode> GetAgentsInGroupAsync(string username, string password, int groupId);
```

How do I work with these xmlnodes to consume them and return information in a web application? In this example, how would I get the agents from the method?

Comment: What did you try? Where *exactly* is your problem with handling XML nodes?

Comment: I want to for instance create a web form and use the GetAgentsInGroup method to display the agents.  I'm really not sure how to do this with an xmlnode contained in an interface.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is way too broad. Stack Overflow works best when you post here *after you tried your best to get it done yourself*. That means reading tutorials and the MSDN pages. And if you have problems with the code, you post it here describing the problems you have. "I don't know" is just too broad to answer here conclusively.

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear, but you are not understanding it. I've explained what I've done to this point, but I don't know what to do next. I have the generated a proxy class via service reference which contains the GetAgentsInGroup method.  The question is how do I implement this method which is an Xmlnode.  How would I display a list of agents on a web form using this method. I've searched several hours on how to do this, so please don't tell me to "read tutorials on MSDN".  This site isn't just for problems with code - sometimes people need direction as well.

Comment: OK, so *what* do you need direction with? You did not show a single line using your interfaces. Do you have problems instantiating a client? Getting data from an XML node? Displaying said data in your GUI?

Comment: I need help getting started or a reference on how to get data from xml nodes that are in an interface.  I don't understand how to use this interface to get the data from the method.  I've tried googling "get data from xmlnode", but can't find anything even remotely similar to the example I've provided.  So to answer your question, I need help with all three of the topics you mentioned.  Instantiating the client and getting the data from the XML node would be a good start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73993/discussion-between-dc922-and-nvoigt).